# I can't connect to SQL Server locally

Tags: sql-server

I have just installed Visual Studio 2010. It comes with SQL Server Express (if am I correct). The problem is: when I try to connect via SQL Server Management Studio Express using `Servername-->BrowseForServer`. There is no SQL Server Express instance just appears `SERVERPC`

So I can't connect this way `.\SERVERPC` or typing or this way `.\SQLEXPRESS`. I checked some protocols like TCP/IP, NamedPipes if they work properly. SQL Server is also running but I can't start SQL Server Agent and SQL Server Browser because all the buttons restart, start and stop are disabled

Answer (score 1):

`Start->All Programs->Sql Server _your version_->Configuration Tools->SQL Server Configuration Manager`.

Go to sql server services and check if there are Sql Server at all (or is it running)

Comment: Sql server is runnig but sql server agent and sql server browser is not .I cant make it run besacuse all the buttons are disabled